# Qual é a importância do README.md no Git ?

Tags: git

Tenho certa dúvida ao uso do README.md pois nunca usei em nenhum projeto e quero saber qual é a sua finalidade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esse arquivo cria a parte inferior dos projetos do github onde tem uma breve explicação do que é, como usar entre outras coisas

`README.md` ou `.mkdn` ou `.markdown` denota que o arquivo é formatado com markdown . O Markdown é uma linguagem de marcação. Com ele você pode facilmente exibir cabeçalhos ou ter palavras em itálico, ou negrito ou quase tudo o que pode ser feito para o texto. O StackOverflow usa isso em seus posts

É importante quando você quer publicar seu projeto e chamar a atenção da comunidade, alguns tópicos importantes:

- Instalação
- Dependências
- Resumo do que é
- Resumo pra que serve
- Vantagens
- Desvantegens
- Exemplos de uso simples
- Exemplos de uso personalizado

(Isso é um markdown de lista)

É importante que essa parte seja completa e atrativa porém evite algo muito longo

Mas se você usa o git apenas para guardar os projetos de curso/faculdade ou pessoais, tanto faz

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655937/what-is-the-difference-between-readme-and-readme-md-in-github-projects) (SO-en), [artigo](http://pichiliani.com.br/como-fazer-um-bom-readme-para-o-seu-github/) (pt-br)

Answer (score 5):

O README.md é um arquivo de texto utilizado para descrever o seu projeto. Ele é essencial se o seu projeto for público, ou seja, visa a criação e a participação de uma comunidade.

Ele nada mais é do que um arquivo de texto onde você poderá descrever, documentar e exemplificar, o seu projeto.

*Ele é um arquivo obrigatório? Não!*
*Se não tiver um arquivo README.md meu projeto continuará a funcionar? Sim!*

- Há ferramentas online que ajudam na construção de um README.md. Exemplo: https://dillinger.io/
- Se tiver dúvidas sobre o que escrever no README.md, há vários artigos que auxiliam nisto. Sugestão: https://www.embarcados.com.br/o-que-escrever-num-readme/